# Error en formateo de fecha

Tags: python, python-2.7

Tengo el siguiente formato de fecha ejemplo:

**may 7  10:32**

¿Cuál seria el formato de fecha que debería utilizar en Python para que lo reconozca? He utilizado el siguiente código, cabe mencionar que esa es la linea que python me indica que tiene un error:

```
date_time="%b-%d %I:%M"%(self.year,file['date'],file['time'])
registro['datetime'] =datetime.strptime(date_time,"%b-%d %I:%M")
```

El error es el siguiente:

> ```
> File "c:\app\appFac\applib\util\tarificado.py", line 831, in processRegistry
>  `introducir el código aquí`date_time="%b-%d %I:%M"%(self.year,file['date'],file['time'])
> KeyError: 'date'
> ```

Comment: ¿Grindor que es `file` y `self.year`?, ¿qué pretendes hacer con la primera línea que muestras? Eso es en principio un "intento" de formateo de cadena, nada que ver con expresiones regulares. El error simplemente dice que `file`, supuestamente un diccionario, no tiene la clave `"date"`.

Comment: Por lo que parece, tu diccionario `file` no tiene la llave `date`